# MySQL: Call Stored Procedure from function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've Stored Procedure in MySQL `String_Split`.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS String_Split;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE String_Split(vString VARCHAR(8000),vSeparator VARCHAR(5))
BEGIN

DECLARE vDone tinyint(1) DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE vIndex INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE vSubString VARCHAR(500);

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmpIDList;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmpIDList (ID varchar(500));

WHILE vDone > 0 DO
  SET vSubString = SUBSTRING(vString, vIndex,
                    IF(LOCATE(vSeparator, vString, vIndex) > 0,
                      LOCATE(vSeparator, vString, vIndex) - vIndex,
                      LENGTH(vString)
                    ));
  IF LENGTH(vSubString) > 0 THEN
      SET vIndex = vIndex + LENGTH(vSubString) + 1;
      INSERT INTO tmpIDList VALUES (vSubString);
  ELSE
      SET vDone = 0;
  END IF;
END WHILE;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm calling this Stored Procedure from function.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS test;
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE FUNCTION test (IDLIST VARCHAR(255))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(2000)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE returnData VARCHAR(2000);

        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP1;       
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEMP1(id bigint);

        CALL String_Split(IDLIST,',');
        INSERT INTO TEMP1 (SELECT * FROM tmpIDList);

        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(first_name) INTO returnData
        FROM user_master 
        WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM TEMP1);

        RETURN returnData;
    End $$
DELIMITER ;
```

But I'm getting following exception

```
Error Code: 1146. Table 'backup25dec_latest.tmpidlist' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce the problem.

It is true that two warnings (NOTE) are generated, but that behavior is documented in [13.1.28 DROP TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-table.html).

```sql
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+-------+------+---------------------------+
| LEVEL | CODE | Message                   |
+-------+------+---------------------------+
| Note  | 1051 | UNKNOWN TABLE 'temp1'     |
| Note  | 1051 | UNKNOWN TABLE 'tmpidlist' |
+-------+------+---------------------------+
2 ROWS IN SET (0.00 sec)
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1feb8/1)</kbd>

Comment: I was using MySQL 5.0 and I think this feature may not available in it. I upgraded to 5.6 and its working fine. Thanks for the concern